# AngularJS: how to produce reports for print?

Tags: angularjs, printing, reporting

I am going to embrace AngularJS, but I have a small doubt about the production of print reports.

My primary need is to print *invoice*-like reports, i.e. use one (HTML+CSS) template for each of my class of reports, with the ability to interpolate data from model.

I see [jsreport](http://jsreport.net/) exists, and looks promising.

The question is:

*Is jsreport the only solution to produce print reports in AngularJS? Do you have alternatives to propose and support?*

Answer (score 1):

I am using **`wkhtmltopdf`** for converting html reports with google graphs and Data Tables to PDF and its working fine for me and This is much easier too, 
You can use this as an alternative.